# How to increase Google signin button width

Tags: android, android-studio-2.1

I am implementing the Google signin functionality in my application.  When i change the width of Google button from *wrap_content* to *match_parent* it show the following error in my xml file. Please help me out.

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Could not resolve resource value: 0x7FFF0030.
        at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.throwException(Resources_Delegate.java:871)
        at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getDrawable(Resources_Delegate.java:138)
        at android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getDrawable(Resources_Delegate.java:126)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:771)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaf.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaf.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.zzar(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.setStyle(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:465)
        at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:172)
        at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
        at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:176)
        at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:247)
        at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:171)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:835)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:838)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
        at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:229)
        at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:426)
        at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
        at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:520)
        at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:508)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:967)
        at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:508)
        at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:75)
        at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:620)
        at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:617)
        at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:371)
        at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:617)
        at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:639)
        at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$7.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:519)
        at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:337)
        at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:327)
        at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$3.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:271)
        at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:286)
        at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:244)
        at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:234)
        at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
        at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:352)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: could you post your layout ?

Comment: Sharma ji, please share your code